# Laravel multi db tenancy with login using main users table

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-10, multi-database, multi-database-connections

I want to do multi db multi tenancy for a saas type  shop app so that users is in main db, and users login using this table, and all shops have different db and users_table have shops db id, and all the shops regarded model uses tenant connection.

I tried using Stancl/Tenancy but its all about domains and subdomains, i want it to be done using single domain and use users_table to store tenant_id and tenant_db_name and initialize tenant from there. If its doable without using tenancy package also its fine.
I am new to laravel so an example will be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, but it will help future noobs like me.

I am building a SAAS application using Laravel, where my requirement is to use a single domain for the central and tenant apps, and each tenant should have it's own database. I came across the stancl/tenancy Laravel package. The problem is that some people, like me, don't understand the documentation due to a lack of experience and language. So here I would try to make it a simple step-by-step guide.

Step 1: install fresh Laravel

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

Step 2: install laravelfortenancy package

```
composer require stancl/tenancy
```

Run the Required Necessary commands

```
php artisan tenancy:install
```

Then add the service provider to your config/app.php file:

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\TenancyServiceProvider::class, // <-- here
```

Now, as my requirement was to use a single domain with multi-database tenancy,. The default behaviour of the package is to use the **web.php** file for central routes and **tenant.php** for tenant routes. For that, I discarded the **tenant.php** file and used **web.php** for both the tenant and central applications.

make customer middleware using command

```
php artisan make:middleware VerifyTenant
```

In verifyTenant, paste this code

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        $user = \auth()->user();
        $tenant = $user->tenant;
        if($tenant){
            Tenancy::initialize($tenant);
        }
    }else{
        return Redirect::route("login");
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

In **web.php** all the routes belongs to central just on bottom of web.php paste this code. This is specific middleware you can put all tenants route.

```
Route::middleware(["verifyTenant"])->group(function () {
    
});
```

This way when you hit any route maybe it central or tenant it filtered and secured by middleware.

> The Answer is sole purpose of learning and maybe not the best possible solution. This is my personal experience maybe I forgot to mention something or have done something wrong but I'm currently building SAAS and so far I don't see any problem with these configuration and setup. Any suggestion or improvements are welome. Sorry for my bad English :)